# storing multi-type data in untyped memory space

Tags: c++, pointers

In following code sample, how can I make *y to point to offset 4?
Right now, only points to offset 0, which is for *x, not *y.

(note that *x & *y will have 4 bytes each)

```
unsigned char *p = new unsigned char[8];
int *x = &*(int *) p;
*x = 1;
int *y = &*(int *) p;
*y = 2;
```

Please dont talk about struct or other ways, they won't help me.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Memory Fragmentation in C++](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9524771/memory-fragmentation-in-c)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are actually storing multiple types in a contiguous buffer, you might be in for a world of pain when it comes to alignment issues. Not all types can be aligned on the same memory boundaries: some might need to be 32-bit aligned, some 64-bit, some 128-bit, and this is all platform-dependent.

[Some reading to get you started](https://web.archive.org/web/20161230020912/http://www.cs.umd.edu/class/sum2003/cmsc311/Notes/Data/aligned.html), but you should read a lot more including the alignment of user-defined types, and for the various compilers and operating systems you are targeting if you really want to do this the way you are doing without using a more structured approach (ex: Variant type approaches combining static and dynamic polymorphism).

In fact, the kind of material you need to understand if you want to do this is quite similar to what you have to learn about data alignment when implementing your own memory allocator (a general memory allocator has to deal with being able to store multiple types in contiguous buffers), so searching for similar topics may give you what you need. I can't help but say that this low-level problem may give you and any co-workers a lot more grief than anyone should ever deserve.

You need to know what types need to be aligned to what boundaries (byte, word, doubleword, quadword). It varies as well. You can't necesarily store an int that isn't aligned on word boundaries, for example. On some systems this might take a huge performance penalty for unaligned moves or even crash your program. This is also why structs typically have padding inside to make sure all data is aligned correctly.

However, for your immediate example which isn't mixing types (just integers):

```
unsigned char *p = new unsigned char[sizeof(int) * 2];
int *x = &*(int *) p;
*x = 1;

// advance your unsigned char* pointer by the size of x
p += sizeof x; // or sizeof(int)

int *y = &*(int *) p;
*y = 2;
```

Comment: Thank you. Why this easy solution dont comes to my mind?! :D
Which is better in your opinion, your solution or 111111's?
Which is faster?

Comment: @user1243815 Both are same speed. His uses an integral constant, 4, to increment the pointer. I use a compile-time constant, sizeof(int). I don't make such assumptions about the size of an int, so it's a little more portable. That's the only difference.

Comment: @user1243815 Oh and his uses reinterpret_cast which expresses the danger of this kind of type-xraying code more clearly. Props to him for that. And he also uses int32_t which guarantees 32-bit ints on all platforms. I just use int but I use sizeof(int) to make sure it works regardless of the size.

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <cstdint>

unsigned char *p = new unsigned char[8];
int32_t *x1=reinterpret_cast<int*>(p);
int32_t *x2=reinterpret_cast<int*>(p+4);
```

That said, please you tell us exactly what you are try to do at a wider scope there almost definitely a better way of doing it.

Please also used specifically sized type, this type of programming is fraught with pain.

Comment: Exactly what i was looking for 2 hours...
Thank you.

Comment: OK. I want to store multiple data types in random in memory.
Is there any better way?

Comment: @user1243815 Um, yes there is: `int x = 1; int y = 2;`

Comment: @jrok: I cant to that in my case.

Comment: If it was what you were looking for please accept the answer, if this 'heap' is entire unstructured then no there isn't really much way, but I don't really see why would want to do that. More details about the problem domain and I might be able to help.