# how to know the element type of void* array in c++

Tags: c++, casting, void-pointers

first I'm working on compiler project , I've built a symbol table

```
class SymbolTable
{
    Scope * currScope;
    Scope * rootScope;
...
}

//where scope is 
class Scope{
    Scope();
    Scope * parent;
    MyMap * m;
...
};

//and Mymap is 
class MyMap
{
    static const int mapLength = MAX_LENGTH;
    MapElem * arr[mapLength];
    int hash(char* name);
...
}

//MapElem is

    class MapElem{
        char* name;
        void* elem;
        MapElem * next;
    ...
    }
```

Now the Void* elem , can be ((function , class, variable ,scope)) all of them r classes,
I want to print the Symbol table to check what Yacc and parser are doing !!
I tried to do this :

```
void printScope(Scope *s)
{
    if (s != NULL)
    {
        cout << "{";
        for (int i = 0; i < 71; i++)
        {
            MapElem* tempelem = s->m->getbyId(i);
            while (tempelem != NULL)
            {
                //cout << "element name is" << tempelem->getName();

                if (static_cast <Type*> (tempelem->getElem())){
                    Type* t = (Type*)tempelem->getElem();
                    cout << "element is Class it's name is" << t->getIs_final() << " " << t->get_name() << "(";
                    for (int i = 0; i < t->getInheritedType().size(); i++){
                        if (t->getInheritedType()[i] != NULL)
                        cout << t->getInheritedType()[i]->get_name() << "," << endl;
                    }
                    cout << "):" << endl;
                    printScope(t->getScope());
                }

                else if (static_cast <Function*>(tempelem->getElem())){
                    Function* t = (Function*)tempelem->getElem();
                    cout << "element is Function it's name is" << t->get_final() << " " << t->get_name() << "(";
                    vector<Variable *> paramet = t->getparameters();
                    for (int i = 0;i< paramet.size(); i++){
                        cout << paramet[i]->get_name() << "," << endl;
                    }
                    cout << "):" << endl;
                    printScope(t->getScope());
                }
                else if ((Scope*)tempelem->getElem()){
                    Scope* t = (Scope*)tempelem->getElem();
                    printScope(t);
                }
                else if ((Variable*)tempelem->getElem()){
                    Variable* t = (Variable*)tempelem->getElem();
                    cout << "element is Variable it's name is" << t->getAccessModifier() << " " << t->get_name() << endl;
                }
                tempelem = tempelem->getNext();
            }
        }
        cout << "}"<<endl;
    }


}
```

the code is running perfect but it's doesn't check the [void type] in If statement ,always enter the first condition even the casting is wrong , 
in that order always enter the type even the void is function or variable ???
when I replaced them , also enter the first stmt what ever is it !!!
why that ?? and how I can fix it ?? or how I can know what data type must I cast .

Comment: Simply don't throw away the type information in the first place.

Comment: This is a job for RTTI or virtual functions.

Comment: `static_cast` performs no checks at run time.

Comment: You should use C++ containers, e.g. `std::map`

Comment: I cant use the std::map for educational reason , but in parser I've used

Function * f = (Function *)t->getScope()->m->get(t->get_name());
 if (!f){
  f = new Function();
  f->set_name(t->get_name());
  //f->setReturnType(t->t);
  t->getScope()->m->put(t->get_name(), f);
  f->setScope(new Scope);
  f->getScope()->parent = t->getScope();
 }

and it's run perfect :/

Comment: @user3312095 - Simply put, there is no magic available to get the type information from a void pointer.  It looks like you misinterpreted what `static_cast` did, and wrote a series of code based on this wrong information.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27749698/store-pointers-of-different-type-in-one-array/27749745#27749745

Comment: you mean polymorphism , how I'll do something like that in mymap , that will be more difficult

Comment: @user3312095 `that will be more difficult`  On the contrary -- it would make the code much easier to maintain.  There would be no need for those if() statements, as all you would do is call the virtual function that would be overridden for each class derived from the base.

Comment: @user3312095 Many design patterns originate in compiler construction. Do you know how a Visitor works? It is a way to encapsulate manipulation of e.g. syntax-trees in an OO way. If you are not familiar with it, you could take a look http://isocpp.org/blog/2014/04/cs-251. The course introduces design patterns for expression-tree parsing as a case study.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The traditional answer is to add an enumeration to `MapElem` to indicate the type:

```
class MapElem{
    //Enumeration identifying all the types of map element and indicating the contents of elem.
    typedef enum {
        aFunction,
        aClass,
        aVariable,
        aScope
    } Type;

    char* name;
    Type type; //<---- Tells us what elem really is!
    void* elem;
    MapElem * next;
...
};
```

The more OO way is to introduce a base class and sub-classes for each type.
You might find that a bit cumbersome because the variables types (function,class,variable and scope) are so divergent that your base-class will contain little more than a way of extracting type!
Oh and some method that returns a printable string for inspecting the elements...

You might introduce a virtual member that returns the enumeration type or rely on RTTI.
RTTI is usually a mistake indicating you didn't understand polymorphism or it doesn't really help the situation.
In this case I suspect the latter.