# Is this use of std::array undefined behavior?

Tags: c++, c++11, undefined-behavior

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Aliasing `T*` with `char*` is allowed. Is it also allowed the other way around?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12612488/aliasing-t-with-char-is-allowed-is-it-also-allowed-the-other-way-around)

I'm using a `std::array` of `char`s to hold a value of unknown primitive type, which is no more than 10 bytes long, like so:

```
std::array<char, 10> val;
*reinterpret_cast<double*>(val.data()) = 6.3;
//blah blah blah...
double stuff = *reinterpret_cast<double*>(val.data());
```

I have read that casting back and forth through `char *` is not undefined, because the compiler assumes a `char *` may alias a value of any type. Does this still work when the value is placed in (what I assume is) an array of `char`s inside the object?

Note: I am aware that I could be using a union here, but that would result in a large amount of boilerplate code for what I am doing, and I would like to avoid it if necessary, hence the question.

Comment: Different question, same answer.

Comment: Same question, different words. ;-]

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yes, `std::array< char, 10 >` does not satisfy the alignment requirements of `double` so that `reinterpret_cast` provokes UB.

Try [`std::aligned_storage`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/aligned_storage) instead.

Comment: Alignment! Of course it's something that didn't even occur to me. Thanks for that link, that's exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't matter what the array is contained in.

The standard does not even consider what surrounds something (it's that basic), but does support conversion to/from `char` sequences.

To do this directly via `reinterpret_cast` and assignment, you need to have the buffer correctly aligned.

An alternative is to use `memcpy`, which doesn't care about alignment.

On a related issue, it's generally not a good idea to go down to the binary level. For example, a simple version change of the compiler might make a file of binary-serialized data inaccessible. A main driver for doing this anyway is raw performance considerations.

Comment: Does it support converting an arbitrary `char*` to `double*`? I think the pointer conversion may be lossy. Consider an ABI with different sized pointers.

Comment: What kind of compiler change could cause that to happen?

Comment: A `char` pointer has as fine-grained addressing resolution as any pointer, same as with `void`. The pointer conversion can conceivably be lossy if the buffer isn't correctly aligned. Anyway the data copying can then be *inefficient*.