# Hash define to the first element of an array causing a null point exception

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

I have code that looks like this:

```
char* talk[516] = {(char*)1};
#define testValue (*(int*)talk[0])
```

I receive a  null pointer exception when the following line of code is then called.

```
testValue = 0;
```

Why is that? Haven't all value of the `talk[]` been initialised?

**EDIT**

What I want to do is, there are 516 number values (`float`s and `int`s) which are stored in `char*` array. `testValue` should point to the `int` value that is stored in the first element of the array. The next value along might be `#define testValue2(*(float*)talk[1])`.

Comment: Because all the elements (i.e `char*`) of `talk` is initialized with value `0` (i.e. null pointer).

Comment: I get the same if error if I make that value 1.

Comment: I updated the question to better reflect this.

Comment: It's still ill-formed. What do want to do? `*(int*)talk[0]` is ill-formed too.

Comment: Someone else has written a file which gives names to all 516 elements in the array using the format above. I just want to store values into the correct element of talk[] using the names they have defined.

Comment: The name in this case is 'testValue'. There are 516 number values (floats and ints) which are stored in char* array. testValue should point to the int value that is stored in the first element of the array. 

The next value along might be #define testValue2(*(float)*talk[1])

Comment: I guess I get what you mean. See my updated answer.

Comment: New answer is very helpful. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For `char* talk[516] = {0};`, all the elements (i.e `char*`) of `talk` are initialized with value `0` (i.e. null pointer).

For `char* talk[516] = {(char*)1};`, the 1st element of `talk` is initialized with value `1`, which is not a valid value for pointer. (And the other elements are still initialized as null pointer.) `*(int*)talk[0]` fails, because you're trying convert a `char*` to `int*`, which points to memory address `1`, and then dereference on it.

You should initialize elements with valid value, such as:

```
int i;
float f;
void* talk[516] = {&i, &f, /*...*/};

#define testValue (*(int*)talk[0]) 
#define testValue2 (*(float*)talk[1]) 

testValue = 1; 
testValue2 = 1.5;
```

---

<sup>1. Note if use `new` to initialize elements of `talk`, you need to `delete` them at last.

2. You could use loop to initialize `talk` too.

3. Using `char*` instead of `void*` is confusing, IMO.

4. Consider about using `std::map` instead of macro magic.</sup>

Comment: Interesting - however I was trying to access the first element of the array.

Answer (score 0):

```
char* talk[516] = {0};
```

This means that the elements of the array talk are all `NULL` pointers. So when you try to deference it you get that exception.

Answer (score 0):

See the following substitution sequence

```
testValue = 0;
#
(*(int*)talk[0]) = 0;
#
char* c = talk[0]; // == 1
(*(int*)c) = 0;
#
char* c = talk[0];
int* i = (int*)c; // == ? (*)
(*i) = 0;
```

* [Alignment issues on pointer casting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13881487/should-i-worry-about-the-alignment-during-pointer-casting)

Casting a `char*` to `int*` results in undefined behavior, since `int*` has stricter alignment requirements than `char*`.