# Accessing bytes in a long long variable with pointers

Tags: c, pointers, pointer-arithmetic, strict-aliasing

I'm supposed to create a variable

```
long long hex = 0x1a1b2a2b3a3b4a4bULL;
```

and then define 4 pointers that point to 1a1b, 2a2b, 3a3b and 4a4b. I'm then printing the addresses and values of those double bytes.

My approach was to create a pointer

```
long long *ptr1 = &hex;
```

and then use pointer arithmetic to get to the next value. What I realized was that incrementing this pointer would increment it by long long bytes and not by 2 bytes like I need it to. Creating a short pointer

```
short *ptr1 = &hex;
```

Is what I would need but my compiler won't let me since the data types are incompatible. How do I get around that? Is there a way to create a pointer that increments by 2 bytes and assign that to a variable of a larger data type?

Comment: Please show a [MCVE]. Or in other words: show your code instead of describing it.

Comment: The 'working' code will violate strict aliasing rules and hence technically be UB. Most compilers will do what you expect, but the Standard doesn't guarantee that anything (good) will happen.

Comment: @MichaelWalz I'll keep that in mind for next time, I also edited my post!

Comment: _Hey Dennis, I removed the solution from the question and had put that in my answer (nothing personal, since you accepted my answer, I thought it's best to put it there). A question needs to be a question, it's no place for an answer. Please let me know if you think otherwise. Thank you._

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can access any variable only through compatible types.

However, a `char` pointer can be used to access any type of variable.

***Please do not cast*** it to a `short*` <sup>Please see NOTE below</sup> , they are not compatible types. You can only use a `char*` for conforming code.

Quoting `C11`, chapter §6.3.2.3

> [...] When a pointer to an object is converted to a pointer to a character type,
>   the result points to the lowest addressed byte of the object. Successive increments of the
>   result, up to the size of the object, yield pointers to the remaining bytes of the object.

So, the way out is, use a `char *` and use pointer arithmetic to get to the required address.

---

NOTE: *Since all other answers suggest a blatantly wrong method (casting the pointer to `short *`, which explicitly violates strict aliasing), let me expand a bit on my answer and supporting quotes.*

Quoting `C11`, chapter §6.5/P7

> An object shall have its stored value accessed only by an lvalue expression that has one of
>   the following types: <sup>88)</sup>
>
> — a type compatible with the effective type of the object,
>
> — a qualified version of a type compatible with the effective type of the object,
>
> — a type that is the signed or unsigned type corresponding to the effective type of the
>   object,
>
> — a type that is the signed or unsigned type corresponding to a qualified version of the
>   effective type of the object,
>
> — an aggregate or union type that includes one of the aforementioned types among its
>   members (including, recursively, a member of a subaggregate or contained union), or
>
> — a character type.

In this case, a `short` and a `long long` are not **compatiable** types. so the only way out is to use `pointer to`char` type.

---

#### Cut-'n-Paste from Question body

**<sup>*This was added as update by OP*</sup>**

Edit:
Here's the correct solution that doesn't cause undefined behavior.
Edit 2:
Added the memory address.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
    long long hex = 0x1a1b2a2b3a3b4a4bULL;
    char *ptr = (char*)&hex;
    int i; int j;
    for (i = 1, j = 0; i < 8, j < 7; i += 2, j += 2) {
        printf("0x%hx%hx at address %p \n", ptr[i], ptr[j], (void *) ptr+i);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Isn't this what the OP wants though? whether or not someone considers it bad/good practice?

Comment: @kabanus It's not about practice, it's wrong to use different  incompatible types.

Comment: So I would need to create 8 pointers? My assignment only wants 4 so I'm suspecting they want it done with short pointers.. your way, it would look like this for the first 2 bytes:

    `char *ptr1 = (char*)&hex+1;`
    `char *ptr2 = (char*)&hex;`

    `printf("%hx%hx", *ptr1, *ptr2);`

Is there a way to format that a bit more efficiently?

Comment: @Dennis Although this is the correct answer, your assignment probably expects code as in e.g. Lanting's answer. Just keep in mind it's undefined behavior and never use something like this in a real-world software. For a way avoiding the undefined behavior (but not the implementation-defined result), see my answer.

Comment: @Dennis No, you don;t need 8 pointers. Notice the part.. _"...Successive increments of the result, up to the size of the object, yield pointers to the remaining bytes of the object."_ So, you can have only one pointer and using pointer arithmetic, you can _get_ the required values.

Comment: @SouravGhosh I added my solution using char pointers to my original post.

Comment: @FelixPalmen I looked at your answer but we haven't covered unions yet.. so I'll have to read up on those before I can make sense of that. Thanks, though!

Answer (score 2):

As expected, it has been pointed out that this is undefined behavior. It's probably one of these stupid "C course" assignments where C isn't completely understood.

Just in case you want to avoid the UB, you could solve it using a `union`:

```
#include <stdio.h>

union longparts
{
    unsigned long long whole;
    unsigned short parts[4];
};

int main(void)
{
    union longparts test;
    test.whole = 0x1a1b2a2b3a3b4a4bULL;

    for (int i = 0; i < 4; ++i)
    {
        unsigned short *part = &test.parts[i];
        printf("short at addr %p: 0x%hx\n", (void *)part, *part);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

from C11 §6.5.2.3, footnote 95:

> If the member used to read the contents of a union object is not the same as the member last used to store a value in the object, the appropriate part of the object representation of the value is reinterpreted as an object representation in the new type as described in 6.2.6 (a process sometimes called ‘‘type punning’’). This might be a trap representation.

So, you could still run into problems in some cases with *trap representations*, but at least it's not undefined. The result is *implementation defined*, e.g. because of endianness of the host machine.

Answer (score 1):

add a cast:

```
short *ptr1 = (short*)&hex;
```

However, make sure you pay attention to the [endianness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness) of your platform.
On x86, for instance, data is stored little end first, so

`ptr1[0]` should point to `0x4a4b`

Also pay attention to your platforms actual sizes: long long is at least 64bit, and short is at least 16 bit. If you want to make sure the types are really those sizes, use `uint64_t` and `uint16_t`. You'll get a compiler error if there aren't any types matching those exact sizes available on your system.

Furthermore, take note of alignment. You can use `uint64_t` as `uint16_t[4]`, however not the other way around, as the address of a `uint16_t` is usually dividable by two, and the address of `uint64_t` dividable by 8.

[Should I worry about the alignment during pointer casting?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13881487/should-i-worry-about-the-alignment-during-pointer-casting)

Answer (score 0):

You need to cast the pointer to assign it to a different type:

```
short *ptr1 = (short*)&hex;
```

However, doing this results in implementation-defined behavior, since you're depending on the endianness of the system.

Comment: The results are not implementation defined, the behaviour is undefined, because it breaks the strict aliasing rule.