# Crashed: Thread SIGBUS 0x0000000054f1f000

Tags: android, android-ndk

My users get this error 1k times per day. I have no idea where to start. I have checked first ~20 pages of Google on anything related to this and all questions on stackoverflow, none have helped me.

I am not using NDK in my app.

These crashes are happening on all devices and all android versions.

Here is the trace i got from Crashylitics:

```
        Crashed: Thread
    0  libc.so                        0x400af440 (Missing)
    1  (Missing)                      0x43d61d16 (Missing)
    2  (Missing)                      0x54f1affe (Missing)
    3  libandroid_runtime.so          0x40207325 (Missing)
    4  (Missing)                      0x42c8dbff (Missing)
    5  (Missing)                      0x54f1affe (Missing)
    6  (Missing)                      0x4cb2154e (Missing)
    7  libdvm.so                      0x41799b0e (Missing)
    8  (Missing)                      0x420397e6 (Missing)
    9  (Missing)                      0x43199276 (Missing)
    10 libdvm.so                      0x417caf4b (Missing)
    11 (Missing)                      0x4e5cdd19 (Missing)
    12 libandroid_runtime.so          0x402072ed (Missing)
    13 (Missing)                      0x4cdfe0b6 (Missing)
    14 libdvm.so                      0x417de65d (Missing)
    15 (Missing)                      0x41d7f41a (Missing)
    16 (Missing)                      0x43199276 (Missing)
    17 (Missing)                      0x42c8dc96 (Missing)
    18 (Missing)                      0x42c8dc96 (Missing)
    19 libdvm.so                      0x417f8a99 (Missing)
    20 (Missing)                      0x420127b6 (Missing)
    21 (Missing)                      0x42c8dc96 (Missing)
    22 libdvm.so                      0x417a60da (Missing)
    23 (Missing)                      0x43199276 (Missing)
    24 (Missing)                      0x4e1ef73e (Missing)
    25 (Missing)                      0x420397e6 (Missing)
    26 libdvm.so                      0x41799c7e (Missing)
    27 (Missing)                      0x43199276 (Missing)
    28 libdvm.so                      0x417a2eea (Missing)
    29 (Missing)                      0x43199276 (Missing)
    30 libdvm.so                      0x417aa4f2 (Missing)
    31 libdvm.so                      0x417aa4a2 (Missing)
    32 libdvm.so                      0x417a79d6 (Missing)
    33 (Missing)                      0x4cabeeae (Missing)
    34 (Missing)                      0x4dcb376e (Missing)
    35 libdvm.so                      0x417de657 (Missing)
    36 libc.so                        0x400e0032 (Missing)
    37 libdvm.so                      0x417d2b73 (Missing)
    38 libdvm.so                      0x417ee4d3 (Missing)
    39 libdvm.so                      0x4181a08a (Missing)
    40 (Missing)                      0x4cabeeae (Missing)
    41 libdvm.so                      0x417de67b (Missing)
    42 libdvm.so                      0x4181a08a (Missing)
    43 (Missing)                      0x4cabeeae (Missing)
    44 libdvm.so                      0x417d2c53 (Missing)
    45 libdvm.so                      0x417d2b73 (Missing)
    46 libdvm.so                      0x417d2b73 (Missing)
    47 libc.so                        0x400965b2 (Missing)
    48 libc.so                        0x400ae94c (Missing)
    49 libbinder.so                   0x4017facd (Missing)
    50 libbinder.so                   0x4017b90f (Missing)
    51 libc.so                        0x4009dfee (Missing)
    52 libc.so                        0x4009717a (Missing)
    53 libbinder.so                   0x401823f5 (Missing)
    54 libbinder.so                   0x40182461 (Missing)
    55 libbinder.so                   0x4017b771 (Missing)
    56 libgui.so                      0x4030bde9 (Missing)
    57 (Missing)                      0x4200ffff (Missing)
    58 libutils.so                    0x4012b813 (Missing)
    59 libandroid_runtime.so          0x401fb9c7 (Missing)
    60 (Missing)                      0x4cb1d75e (Missing)
    61 libdvm.so                      0x41799b0e (Missing)
    62 (Missing)                      0x4203610e (Missing)
    63 libdvm.so                      0x417caf4b (Missing)
    64 (Missing)                      0x4e5cd841 (Missing)
    65 libandroid_runtime.so          0x401fb9e1 (Missing)
    66 (Missing)                      0x4cb25316 (Missing)
    67 libdvm.so                      0x417de65d (Missing)
    68 (Missing)                      0x4e974c1e (Missing)
    69 (Missing)                      0x42b96456 (Missing)
    70 (Missing)                      0x4265745a (Missing)
    71 (Missing)                      0x42657456 (Missing)
    72 libdvm.so                      0x417d047b (Missing)
    73 (Missing)                      0x4e336b84 (Missing)
    74 (Missing)                      0x4203610e (Missing)
    75 libdvm.so                      0x41799c7e (Missing)
    76 libdvm.so                      0x417a2eea (Missing)
    77 libdvm.so                      0x417aa4f2 (Missing)
    78 libdvm.so                      0x417aa4a2 (Missing)
    79 libdvm.so                      0x417a79d6 (Missing)
    80 (Missing)                      0x42029446 (Missing)
    81 (Missing)                      0x4ea60b86 (Missing)
    82 (Missing)                      0x4cac55e6 (Missing)
    83 (Missing)                      0x41d67ffe (Missing)
    84 (Missing)                      0x426568a6 (Missing)
    85 (Missing)                      0x4cb96676 (Missing)
    86 (Missing)                      0x4265693a (Missing)
    87 (Missing)                      0x42656862 (Missing)
    88 libdvm.so                      0x417de993 (Missing)
    89 (Missing)                      0x4200e2a6 (Missing)
    90 (Missing)                      0x42656926 (Missing)
    91 (Missing)                      0x42656926 (Missing)
    92 libdvm.so                      0x417f8a99 (Missing)
    93 (Missing)                      0x4200ee8e (Missing)
    94 (Missing)                      0x42656926 (Missing)
    95 libdvm.so                      0x417a60da (Missing)
    96 (Missing)                      0x426568a6 (Missing)
    97 (Missing)                      0x42074fa6 (Missing)
```

UPD: Here is my app gradle:

```
    buildscript {
        repositories {
            maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
        }

        dependencies {
            classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.+'
        }
    }
    //noinspection GradleCompatible
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
    apply plugin: 'io.fabric'

    repositories {
        maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
    }

    apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
    apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'
    apply plugin: 'io.fabric'

    android {
        dexOptions {
            javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
        }
        signingConfigs {
        }
        compileSdkVersion 25
        buildToolsVersion '25.0.2'
        defaultConfig {
            multiDexEnabled true
            minSdkVersion 15
            targetSdkVersion 25
        }
        buildTypes {
            release {
                minifyEnabled true
                proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            }
            debug {
                ext.enableCrashlytics = false
            }
        }

        productFlavors {
            normal {
                applicationId "xxx"
                versionCode 1
                versionName "1"
            }
        }

        packagingOptions {
            exclude 'META-INF/ASL2.0'
            exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
            exclude 'META-INF/MANIFEST.MF'
            exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
            exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
            exclude 'META-INF/license.txt'
            exclude 'META-INF/license'
            exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
            exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
            exclude 'META-INF/notice.txt'
            exclude 'META-INF/notice'
        }
    }

    dependencies {
        compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
        compile "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:$kotlin_version"
        compile "org.jetbrains.anko:anko-common:$anko_version"
        compile group: 'com.pubnub', name: 'pubnub-gson', version: '4.14.0'
        compile group: 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core', name: 'jackson-core', version: '2.9.0'
        compile group: 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core', name: 'jackson-databind', version: '2.9.0'

        //    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:10.0.0'
    //    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:10.0.0

    //    debugCompile 'com.squareup.leakcanary:leakcanary-android:1.5.4'
    //    releaseCompile 'com.squareup.leakcanary:leakcanary-android-no-op:1.5.4'

        compile('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.8.0@aar') {
            transitive = true;
        }
        compile('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics-ndk:2.0.1@aar') {
            transitive = true;
        }

        compile 'com.parse.bolts:bolts-tasks:1.4.0'
        compile 'com.parse:parse-android:1.16.3'
        compile 'com.appsflyer:af-android-sdk:4.8.5'
        compile 'com.android.installreferrer:installreferrer:1.0'
        compile 'com.flurry.android:analytics:6.4.2'
        compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
        compile 'com.android.support:preference-v7:25.3.1'
        compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
        compile 'com.android.support:design:25.3.1'
        compile 'com.github.chrisbanes:PhotoView:1.2.6'
        compile 'com.theartofdev.edmodo:android-image-cropper:2.4.7'
        compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.1'
        compile 'com.vdurmont:emoji-java:3.3.0'
        compile 'com.scottyab:aescrypt:0.0.1'
        compile 'io.branch.sdk.android:library:1.14.5'
        compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:11.0.4'
        compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:11.0.4'
        compile 'com.otaliastudios:cameraview:1.4.1'
        compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    }

    apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

    crashlytics {
        enableNdk true
    }
```

Comment: are you using any project as a module?

Comment: I am using lots of libraries, but no projects as modules.

Comment: Well, and how should anyone help you? You have probably found what causes this error. So, the goal is clear, you need to find the code that causes it. Unless it's clear by then, you could then extract a minimal example fit for posting here.

Comment: any of your lib project use .so file. try to find gradle injection for your projects. and add as a gradle dependency and remove that project.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt I have not found what causes the error, if i would i would fix it and not make a question here.

Comment: @KuLdipPaTel Could you please elaborate a bit? I have only one project. What should I add as a gradle dependency? Which project to remove? I don't use any projects as dependencies.

Comment: Well, @lxknvlk, at least you should know what in general causes bus errors.

Comment: can you please provide app level gradle? so i can help on that.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt I have learned that that is an access attempt to a memory location that is not there. Like a null pointer in ndk. But this info gives me absolutely nothing to continue.

Comment: @KuLdipPaTel i have added gradle file

Comment: update `com.fasterxml.jackson.core` and `com.pubnub` maven repo this may help you.

Comment: @KuLdipPaTel thanks, i will try it.

Answer (score 1):

Without having access to the source I can't be certain, but in AOSP we almost always saw these errors as a result of casts which were undefined behavior (described in [Should I worry about the alignment during pointer casting?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13881487/632035)).

Some ARM instructions will fault on unaligned loads. These instructions are also faster than those that can be used for an unaligned load. If the compiler believes the load will be aligned, it will generate the faster code. If the load then *isn't* actually aligned, you'll get the fault you're seeing here.

These can be tricky to track down, but typically the problem is as shown in the other question I linked: there's a character buffer somewhere that is being cast to some other more strictly aligned type of data. You should be able to find it based on the crash dump.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the problem. I tracked it by checking in which version did these crashes appear, and what i have added in that version. No other way found for tracking such problem.

The problem was i used one weird method to avoid OutOfMemory exceptions, that tried to use the sd card as ram in certain conditions. I suppose on devices without external sd card this was a problem.