# Why is this example using memcpy to convert uint8_t* parameter to a structure?

Tags: c++

I was using a TCP library that has an incoming data handler with the following signature:

```
static void handleData(void *arg, AsyncClient *client, void *data, size_t len)
```

When I tried to cast the `data` like the following the access the field values of the structure, the board crashed.

```
MyStructure* m = (MyStructure*)data;
```

[In an example of an unrelated communication library](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/RuiSantosdotme/Random-Nerd-Tutorials/master/Projects/ESP8266/ESP_NOW/ESP_NOW_Two_Way.ino), I had seen it using `memcpy` like the following, so I changed the casting code above to `memcpy` then it worked. But why is the example using `memcpy` instead of casting?

```
// Callback when data is received
void OnDataRecv(uint8_t * mac, uint8_t *incomingData, uint8_t len) {
  memcpy(&incomingReadings, incomingData, sizeof(incomingReadings));
  incomingTemp = incomingReadings.temp;
  incomingHum = incomingReadings.hum;
}
```

The `incomingReadings` is declared as a global variable, but that variable is only used inside of that function, and only the fields which are copied to other global variables `incomingTemp` and `incomingHum` are used elsewhere. What if the example function were like the following, would it crash?

```
void OnDataRecv(uint8_t * mac, uint8_t *incomingData, uint8_t len) {
  struct_message* incoming = (struct_message*)incomingData;
  incomingTemp = incoming->temp;
  incomingHum = incoming->hum;
}
```

---

PS: About the crashing above, I have tested more things to reproduce it with simpler code. It seems that the board does not crash at casting, but at accessing the cast variable.

The structure is as simple as

```
typedef struct TEST_TYPE
{
    unsigned long a;
} TEST_TYPE;
```

and in the client, I sent `a` in

```
  TEST_TYPE *a = new TEST_TYPE();
  a->a = 1;
```

. In the server's `handleData`, I modified the code like below

```
static void handleData(void *arg, AsyncClient *client, void *data, size_t len)
{
    Serial.printf("Data length = %i\n", len);
    
    uint8_t* x = (uint8_t*)data;
    for(int i =0; i<len; i++)
    {
        Serial.printf("%X, ", x[i]);
    }

    Serial.println("Casting.");
    TEST_TYPE* a = (TEST_TYPE*)data;

    Serial.println("Printing.");
    Serial.printf("\nType = %i\n", a->a);
```

, and the output was

```
Data length = 4
1, 0, 0, 0, Casting.
Printing.

--------------- CUT HERE FOR EXCEPTION DECODER ---------------

Exception (9):
epc1=0x40201117 epc2=0x00000000 epc3=0x00000000 excvaddr=0x3fff3992 depc=0x00000000

>>>stack>>>

ctx: sys
sp: 3fffec30 end: 3fffffb0 offset: 0190
```

PS2: Seems like it indeed is an alignment issue. The exception code is 9 above, and [according to this page](https://arduino-esp8266.readthedocs.io/en/latest/exception_causes.html), 9 means:

> LoadStoreAlignmentCause Load or store to an unaligned address

[I have found an old answer for a similar case](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/a/67450/67661). The author suggested some possible solutions

1. adding `__attribute__((aligned(4)))` to the buffer: I think this is not applicable in my case, because I did not create the `data` parameter.
2. adding `__attribute__((packed))` to the structure: I have modified my structure like the following, and it did not crash this time.

   ```
    typedef struct TEST_TYPE
    {
        unsigned long a;
    } __attribute__((packed)) TEST_TYPE;
   ```
3. Read it by each one byte and construct the fields manually: This seems too much work.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13881606/85696

Comment: I had written my answer right before @danadam posted their comment, I think danadam is correct, alignment issue is probably what's going on. Somebody want to write a proper answer for this?

Comment: @danadam It indeed was an alignment issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Without the full picture of the lifetimes of all the data, it's hard to say what's going wrong in your particular case. Some thoughts:

```
uint8_t *bytes;
...
MyStructure* m = (MyStructure*)bytes;
```

What the snippet above is doing is using `m` to interpret the region of memory pointed to by `bytes` as a `MyStructure`. It's important to note that `m` is only valid as long as `bytes` is valid. When `bytes` goes out of scope (or freed, etc.), `m` is no longer valid.

```
uint8_t *bytes;
MyStructure m;
...
memcpy(&m, bytes, sizeof(MyStructure));
```

This snippet is **copying** the data referred to by bytes into `m`. At this point, `m`'s lifetime is separate from `bytes`. Note that you could do the same thing with this syntax:

```
uint8_t *bytes;
MyStructure m;
...
m = *((MyStructure*)bytes)
```

This snippet is saying "treat bytes as a pointer to a MyStructure, then dereference the pointer and make a copy of it".

As @danadam points out in a comment, `memcpy()` should be used in the case of alignment issues.

Comment: I think that from standard point of view, `memcpy` would be required even if alignment was right. But depending on which compiler you use, it might works.

Comment: @effect It indeed was an alignment issue. Please see the added text to my original posting.

Answer (score 4):

Would it crash? Perhaps.

Essentially you're touching *alignment* and *aliasing* here.
The rules are here:
https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/object#Alignment

Your struct most probably has higher alignment requirements than 1 and therefore it depends on where in the memory the converted bytes are located if it will crash or not. As neither you nor the compiler can be sure of that, the cast is undefined behavior.
The only way your cast from void* to MyStructure* wouldn't be UB is when the void* was casted from a MyStructure* in the first place.
uint8 / char etc. have minimal alignment requirements (only 1 byte) and are therefore valid anywhere in a chunk of memory. That can be used to copy the memory into your correctly aligned object.