# Unexpected results with std::ofstream binary write

Tags: c++, iostream

I'm new to C++ std::stream and I'm making some tests. I have this simple code:

```
int i = 10;
char c = 'c';
float f = 30.40f;

std::ofstream out("test.txt", std::ios::binary | std::ios::out);
if(out.is_open())
{
    out<<i<<c<<f;
    out.close();
}
```

As the stream is opened as `std::ios::binary` I expect in the `test.txt` file to have the binary representation of `i`, `c` and `f`, but instead I have `10c30.4`.

Can you please tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: From http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/fstream/ofstream/ofstream/ binary (binary) Consider stream as binary rather than text.

Comment: Okay, on to the POSIX definitions of text file streams vs. binary file streams then :) (Hint: why would writing **text** to a binary file result in something else than text?)

Comment: @Felics: the standard does not specify what "binary" actually means. In fact on some platforms it has no effect (e.g. on POSIX).

Comment: To be perfectly clear: +1 for this question. I think it is interesting to find that [documentation on this](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ios/ios_base/openmode/) is very sketchy. It is apparently "assumed" to be obvious. More people might be confused, which makes this a perfect [SO] candidate.

Comment: @ybungalobill In common perception binary means "what is in memory". When using FILE* with "wb" flag I have the expected result.

Comment: @Felics: your last sentence makes no sense. ISO says that opening an `fstream` with `binary|out` is *equivalent* to `fopen` with `"wb"` mode. Now, when you say "I have the expected result" it means that you called `fwrite`, which corresponds to `ostream::write`. But your code here uses `operator <<`, which corresponds to, e.g. `fprintf(out, "%d", i)` for integers.

Comment: @Felics but then you'd have used `(f)write`, not `fprintf`. The latter corresponds to `std::ostream` `operator<<`

Answer (score 18, accepted):

`std::ios::binary` promises to not do any line-end conversions on the stream (and some other small behavioral differences with text streams).

You could look at

- Boost Serialization http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/libs/serialization/doc/index.html
- Boost Spirit binary generators http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/libs/spirit/doc/html/spirit/karma/reference/binary/
- Using ofstream::write(...) to manually write the bytes

Here's an example using Boost Spirit Karma (assuming Big-Endian byte ordering):

```
#include <boost/spirit/include/karma.hpp>
namespace karma = boost::spirit::karma;

int main()
{
    int i = 10;
    char c = 'c';
    float f = 30.40f;

    std::ostringstream oss(std::ios::binary);
    oss << karma::format(
            karma::big_dword << karma::big_word << karma::big_bin_float, 
            i, c, f);

    for (auto ch : oss.str())
        std::cout << std::hex << "0x" << (int) (unsigned char) ch << " ";
    std::cout << "\n";
}
```

This prints

```
0x0 0x0 0x0 0xa 0x0 0x63 0x41 0xf3 0x33 0x33
```

Comment: I've added a demo based on Karma, see also here: **[http://liveworkspace.org/code/4B5okj](http://liveworkspace.org/code/4B5okj)**

Comment: That's not quite "end of story", there are various possible transformations that can be performed on text files, including that the data read back may differ from the data written (e.g. trim trailing space), and some file operations such as `fseek` behave differently for each type.

Answer (score 18):

In order to write raw binary data you have to use [ostream::write](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ostream/ostream/write/). It does not work with the output operators.

Also make sure if you want to read from a binary file not to use operator>> but instead [istream::read](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/istream/istream/read/).

The links also provide examples how you can handle binary data.

So for your example:

```
int i = 10;
char c = 'c';
float f = 30.40f;

std::ofstream out("test.txt", std::ios::binary | std::ios::out);
if(out.is_open())
{
    out.write(reinterpret_cast<const char*>(&i), sizeof(i));
    out.write(&c, sizeof(c));
    out.write(reinterpret_cast<const char*>(&f), sizeof(f));
    out.close();
}
```

Comment: beware of UB and unportability when doing this. I'd suggest using well tested libraries to handle this for you, and account for endianness (Boost Spirit, Serialization, protobuf etc.)

Comment: Yes, you are right. But I just wanted to point to an answer with plain C++ without any boost or other libraries.

Comment: E.g. the sample technically requires `reinterpret_cast<const char*>` to not invoke Undefined Behaviour, I think. (PS. I _did_ point to the answer in plain C++ too :))

Comment: @sehe That (= the code not invoking UB) is guaranteed by the standard, actually. The *result* of doing this, now *that* is unspecified.

Comment: Please read this Q/A http://stackoverflow.com/q/12612488/85371 for a healthy introduction to the risks of reinterpreting object pointers

Comment: I think you're missing a `&` or three. And a couple of `sizeof`s.