# How do I read doubles from a binary file in a loop?

Tags: python, numpy

Simple question, but I don't find a helpful answer on the web. I have file create with C++, where I first output a `std::size_t k`  and then write `2 * x` `double`s.

I need to first read the `std::size_t k` in python and then iterate in a loop from `0` to `k - 1`, read two `double x, y` in each iteration and do something with them:

```
with open('file', 'r') as f:
    fig, ax = pyplot.subplots()
    k = numpy.fromfile(f, numpy.uint64)[0] # does not work
    for j in range(0, k):
        # get double x and y somehow
        x = numpy.fromfile(f, numpy.double)[0]
        y = numpy.fromfile(f, numpy.double)[0]
        ax.scatter(x = x, y = y, c = 0)
        ax.set_xlim(0, 1)
        ax.set_ylim(0, 1)
```

The value I read in `k` is `3832614067495317556`, but it should be `4096`. And at the point where I read `x`, I immediately get an index out of range exception.

Comment: Do you have C++ code that you can share that created the input file? That might make it easier to reproduce your problem.

Comment: Note that the consecutive reads won't really work: `fromfile` reads the file as an array. You'll need `count=1` to read at least item by item (or `count=2`. And use `offset=8`; you can probably read all doubles in one go, with that; and only then iterate over them.

Comment: I assume you've double checked that `std::size_t` is equal to `uint64` for your machine?

Comment: Depending on your platform/OS, open the file in binary mode: `with open('file', 'rb') as f:`. In particular on Windows, this makes a difference. On any Unix-style OS, as far as I'm aware, this doesn't make a difference (so it doesn't hurt either, and using 'rb' is then better for portability and clarity reasons).

Comment: @9769953 It is simply `std::ofstream out("file", std::ios_base::binary); std::size_t k = 4096; out << k`. And then I write the `double`s. And yes, `std::size_t` has 8 bytes on my platform.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14767857/unexpected-results-with-stdofstream-binary-write

Comment: Look at the hexdump of the output file; you would find it's definitely not 4096 in the first 8 bytes. Which indicates the C++ is wrong, not the Python code (though that also has mistakes).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your C++ code is wrong. The standard `<<` operator doesn't behave well with binary data.

Use the following:

```
#include <fstream>

int
main()
        std::ofstream out("file.dat", std::ios::binary);
        std::size_t k = 4096;
        out.write(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&k), sizeof k);

        double a = 1.1;
        for (int i = 0; i < 8; ++i) {
                auto b = a*i;
                out.write(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&b), sizeof b);
        }
}
```

See the example at the bottom of https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ofstream, where I grabbed this from.

---

(Answer related to improvements and mistakes of the Python code, even if that's not the essential problem.)

Open the file in binary mode (necessary on Windows), read just 1 item for the size, and read all the remaining doubles in one go using the `offset` parameter. Also verify that `std::size_t` is equal to `uint64` for the relevant machine(s).

```
import numpy as np

with open('file.dat', 'rb') as f:
    fig, ax = pyplot.subplots()
    # count in items, offset in bytes
    k = np.fromfile(f, np.uint64, count=1)[0]
    # Might need to move the file pointer back to the start
    f.seek(0)
    xy = np.fromfile(f, np.double, offset=8)
    for x, y in zip(xy[::2], xy[1::2]):
        ax.scatter(x = x, y = y, c = 0)
        ax.set_xlim(0, 1)
        ax.set_ylim(0, 1)
```

If you're not doing anything special with the scatter plots, and just want to plot all data in one scatter plot, you don't need a for-loop:

```
import numpy as np

with open('file.dat', 'rb') as f:
    fig, ax = pyplot.subplots()
    # count in items, offset in bytes
    k = np.fromfile(f, np.uint64, count=1)[0]
    # Might need to move the file pointer back to the start
    f.seek(0)
    xy = np.fromfile(f, np.double, offset=8)
    ax.scatter(x = xy[::2], y = xy[1::2], c = np.zeros(len(xy)/2))
    ax.set_xlim(0, 1)
    ax.set_ylim(0, 1)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. In your last code, `c = 0` does not work. It seems to expect an array of the same dimension as `x` and `y`. How can we fix this?

Comment: @0xbadf00d Good point, I overlooked that. I think `c = np.zeros(len(xy)/2)` can fix that (untested); see also my updated answer.