# Why can a pointer still modify const reference object inside function?

Tags: c++

Assume I have Student class like this:

```cpp
class Student {
  private:
    std::string _name;
  public:
    Student(const std::string&);
    void setName(const std::string&);
    const std::string& getName() const;
};
```

And a function which is like:

```cpp
void changeConstRefObj(const Student& student){
   std::string newName = ....;
   student.setName(newName);
}
```

Which is invalid when you call `setName`. But you can still use a pointer to call `setName` (which does not use `static_cast`, may be something wrong with compiler?) like this:

```cpp
void changeConstRefObj(const Student& student)
{
    std::string newName = ...;
    Student *p = (Student*)(&student);
    p->setName(newName);
}
```

Or using new object like this one below (which I don't know why it works).

```cpp
void changeConstRefObj(const Student& student)
{
    std::string newName = ...;
    Student t(newName);
    Student *p = (Student*)(&student);
    *p = t;
}
```

I thought that if I use const that I wouldn't be able to change the object but through a pointer I can change it easily. Why is that the case?

Comment: `I thought that if I use const that I can not change object` correct. `but through pointer I can change it easily.` because you casted away the constness.

Comment: This is why C-style casts (at least for pointers and references) are unsafe...

Comment: The `const` keyword is there to help you avoid making mistakes; that doesn't mean you can't defeat it (by casting-away-const using `const_cast<Student *>(&student)`, or C-style casting as in your example) and make those mistakes anyway, if you really want to.  As the saying goes, `const` is meant to protect you from Murphy, not Machiavelli.

Comment: It's worth mentioning that even if this runs, it's undefined behavior. C++ is allowed to assume that variables declared `const` will not change, so the compiler can optimize around that fact freely

Comment: *"which does not use `static_cast`"* -- misleading at best (and I think you meant `const_cast` here, as a `static_cast` cannot remove `const`). Your code uses a [C-style cast](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/cast), which can do everything `const_cast` can do, plus more.

Comment: Found a related question instead of a true duplicate: [I'm changing the value of a const variable by accessing the memory location. Why doesn't it work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27258089/im-changing-the-value-of-a-const-variable-by-accessing-the-memory-location-why) I guess that other question would be the next step from this one, as it assumes your syntax works.