# The right way to work with network buffer in modern GCC/C++ without breaking strict-aliasing rules

Tags: c++, c++11, gcc, strict-aliasing

The program - some sort of old-school network messaging:

```
// Common header for all network messages.
struct __attribute__((packed)) MsgHeader {
    uint32_t msgType;
};
// One of network messages.
struct __attribute__((packed)) Msg1 {
    MsgHeader header;
    uint32_t field1;
};

// Network receive buffer.
uint8_t rxBuffer[MAX_MSG_SIZE];

// Receive handler. The received message is already in the rxBuffer.
void onRxMessage() {
    // Detect message type
    if ( ((const MsgHeader*)rxBuffer)->msgType == MESSAGE1 ) { // Breaks strict-aliasing!
        // Process Msg1 message.
        const Msg1* msg1 = (const Msg1*)rxBuffer;
        if ( msg1->field1 == 0 ) { // Breaks strict-aliasing!
            // Some code here;
        }
        return;
    }
    // Process other message types.
}
```

This code violates strict-aliasing in modern GCC (and falls down to unspecified behaviour in modern C++).
What is the correct way to solve the problem (to make the code that doesn't throw the "strict-aliasing" warning)?

P.S. If rxBuffer is defined as:

```
union __attribute__((packed)) {
  uint8_t[MAX_MSG_SIZE] rawData;
} rxBuffer;
```

and then I cast *&rxBuffer* to other pointers it doesn't cause any warnings. But is it safe, right and portable way?

Comment: as far as I can tell, the compiler assuming that msg1 and rxBuffer do not alias will not result in a bug here. would you mind linking or elaborating why it would?

Comment: Union aliasing is not supported by C++. Although you don't actually do that, your "union" only has one member

Comment: But plain structures AND unions ARE aligned as well as their fields and their memory foot-print are defined. That union can be replaced with a structure, but some old and/or buggy compilers might have errors with that (with pointer aliasing). So union is just an additional guard  to make sure the declared type is "plain" (usually unions are better tested for such cases because they are traditionally used in low-level system programing). Plus union marks this type as "unusual" for programmer who might  want to add additional fields or methods to it later and make it non-plain accidentally.

Answer (score 5):

Define `rxBuffer` as a pointer to a `union` of `uint8_t[MAX_SIZE]`, `MsgHeader`, `Msg1` and whatever type you plan to cast to. Note that this would still break the strict aliasing rules, but in GCC it it guaranteed to work as non-standard extension.

EDIT: if such a method would lead to a too complicated declaration, a fully portable (if slower) way is to keep the buffer as a simple `uint8_t[]` and `memcpy` it to the opportune message struct as soon as it has to be reinterpreted. The feasability of this method obviously depends on your performance and efficiency needs.

<strike>EDIT 2: a third solution (if you are working on "normal" architectures) is to use `char` or `unsigned char` instead of `uint8_t`. Such types are guaranteed to alias everything.</strike> Not valid because the conversion to the message type might not work, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12612488/aliasing-t-with-char-is-allowed-is-it-also-allowed-the-other-way-around)

Comment: This might be very painful to do in the context described. It basically requires that the code doing the network IO knows all the possible message layouts used by the application. This introduces a coupling from the network code to all kinds of higher-level components.

Comment: I would not see it in this way... from the code it seems that the function `onRxMessage` is making some higher level computation, so it must know of the message types. The lower-level IO system can work even only with the address of the `uint8_t` field of the union, it doen not need to know the whole declaration.

Comment: But can I just make "union { uint8_t[MAX_SIZE]; } rxBuffer;" instead?

Comment: No, it won't work. But, as said, only `onRxMessage` is required to know of this union. The lower level functions can just work with the `uint8_t[]` field, you do not need to alter their signature. (i.e. you can pass &rawData to them).

Comment: "Whatever I type I plan to cast" might be a type with variable field length so it can not be declared that easily. And of course it is a VERY painful and twisted way because there can be a lot of message types and they may have different handlers and so on. The first example - IP-header. It can't be described as plain struct/union structure as it has variable length fields, optional fields etc.

Comment: Sorry, I changed my comment because it's impossible to paste readable code in comments :)

Comment: OK, I expanded on my answer. I hope one of the three solutions can fit.

Comment: the "char *" type breaks aliasing as well. uint8_t in GCC is just an unsigned char.

Comment: The must be some problem, `char` is guaranteed by the Standard not to break aliasing

Comment: *char pointer* doesn't break aliasing if you cast **to** the char pointer type, but not **from** it. When you cast from _char*_ the target buffer can be not properly aligned (because char doesn't need any special alignment) and some optimisation may cause serious platform-dependant issues. So u can convert everything to _char*_ but u can not convert _char*_ to everything that's what the Standard says I guess.

Comment: [You are right](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12612488/aliasing-t-with-char-is-allowed-is-it-also-allowed-the-other-way-around). My bad. that leaves only the first two options.

Answer (score 2):

By working with the individual bytes, you can avoid all pointer casting and eliminate portability issues with endianness and alignment:

```
uint32_t decodeUInt32(uint8_t *p) {
    // Decode big-endian, which is network byte order.
    return (uint32_t(p[0])<<24) |
           (uint32_t(p[1])<<16) |
           (uint32_t(p[2])<< 8) |
           (uint32_t(p[3])    );
}

void onRxMessage() {
    // Detect message type
    if ( decodeUInt32(rxBuffer) == MESSAGE1 ) {
        // Process Msg1 message.
        if ( decodeUInt32(rxBuffer+4) == 0 ) {
            // Some code here;
        }
        return;
    }
    // Process other message types.
}
```

Comment: This is the best way spend like 1000x times more CPU time and get big asspain. How do u see decoding of any serious protocol with this way and supporting of the code later (you would have to dive into the deeps every time the protocol has been changed) ?

Comment: @user3544995: I seriously doubt it would make that much difference in performance. I suspect most of the time is going to be spent reading the bytes out of memory. If you have a complex protocol, then having a class to manage the pointer helps a lot.  It can automatically advance the pointer by 4 bytes when you read a 32-bit value, for example. This makes adding new fields only have a local effect on the implementation.

Answer (score 1):

1. Like Alberto M wrote, you can change the type of your buffer and how you receive into it:

   ```
   union {
           uint8_t rawData[MAX_MSG_SIZE];
           struct MsgHeader msgHeader;
           struct {
                   struct MsgHeader dummy;
                   struct Msg1 msg;
           } msg1;
   } rxBuffer;

   receiveBuffer(&rxBuffer.rawData);
   if (rxBuffer.msgHeader.msgType == MESSAGE1) {
           if (rxBuffer.msg1.msg.field1) {
                   // ...
   ```

   or directly receive into the struct, if your receive uses `char`s (`uint8_t` only aliases `uint8_t` unlike `char`, which may always alias):

   ```
   struct {
           struct MsgHeader msgHeader;
           union {
                   struct Msg1 msg1;
                   struct Msg2 msg2;
           } msg;
   } rxBuffer;

   recv(fd, (char *)&rxBuffer, MAX_MSG_SIZE, 0);
   // handle errors and insufficient recv length
   if (rxBuffer.msgHeader.msgType == MESSAGE1) {
           // ...
   ```

   <strike>Btw. type punning through a union **is** standard and doesn't break strict aliasing. See *C99-TC3 6.5 (7)* and also search for "type punning".</strike> The question is about C++, but not C, so Alberto M is right about it being non-standard, but a GCC extension.
2. Using `memcpy` for this works kind of in the same manner like above, but is standard: bytes are copied on per character basis, effectively reinterpreting them as a struct when accessing the destination location, like you would do when you're type punning through a union:

   ```
   struct MsgHeader msgHeader;

   memcpy(&msgHeader, rxBuffer, sizeof(msgHeader));
   if (msg_header.msgType == MESSAGE1) {
           struct Msg1 msg;

           memcpy(&msg, rxBuffer + sizeof(msgHeader), sizeof(msg));
           if (msg.field1 == 0) {
                   // Some code here;
           }
   }
   ```
3. Or like Vaughn Cato wrote, you can unpack (and should then probably also pack) the received and sent network buffers yourself. Again it's standard compliant and this way you also work around padding and byte order in a portable way:

   ```
   uint8_t *buf= rxBuffer;
   struct MsgHeader msgHeader;

   msgHeader.msgType = (buf[3]<<0) | (buf[2]<<8) | (buf[1]<<16) | (buf[0]<<24); // read uint32_t in big endian
   if (msgHeader.msgType == MESSAGE2) {
           struct Msg2 msg;

           buf += sizeof(MsgHeader);
           msg.field1 = (buf[1]<<0) | (buf[0]<<8); // read uint16_t in big endian
           if (msg.field1 == 0) {
                   // ...
   ```

Note: `struct Msg1` and `struct Msg2` don't contain a `struct MsgHeader` in the above snippets and are like this:

```
struct Msg1 {
    uint32_t field1;
};

struct Msg2 {
    uint16_t field1;
};
```

Comment: *"Btw. type punning through a union is standard"* In C. Not in C++. However gcc allows it in C++ as well (extension).

Comment: Ah, my fault. I saw the code and assumed automatically that it's about C without checking the tags. Yes, 1. is not an actual portable solution then and Alberto M was right, so to really be compliant you should use 2. or even better 3.

Answer (score 0):

It boils down to this:

```
 ((const MsgHeader*)rxBuffer)->msgType
```

`rxBuffer` is of one type, but we wish to treat is as if it was of another type. I suggest the following "alias-cast":

```
 const MsgHeader * msg_header_p = (const MsgHeader *) rxBuffer;
 memmove(msg_header_p, rxBuffer, sizeof(MsgHeader));
 auto msg_type = msg_header_p -> msgType;
```

`memmove` (like its less flexible cousin `memcpy`) effectively says that the bit pattern that *was* available at the source (`rxBuffer`) will, after the call to `memmove` be available at the destination (`msg_header_p`). Even if the types are different.

You might argue that `memmove` does "nothing", because the source and destination are identical. But that's exactly the point. *Logically*, it serves the purpose of making `msg_header_p` an alias for `rxBuffer`, even though in practice a good compiler will optimize it out.

*(This answer is potentially a bit controversial. I may be pushing `memmove` too far. I guess my logic is: First, `memcpy` to a new location is clearly acceptable to answer this question; second, `memmove` is just a better, more general (but maybe slower), version of `memcpy`; third, if `memcpy` allows you to look at the same bit pattern via a different type, when why shouldn't `memmove` allow the same idea to "change" the type of a particular bit pattern? If we `memcpy` to a temporary area, then `memcpy` back to the original position, would be OK also? )*

If you want to build a full answer out of this, you'll need to alias-cast back again at some point, `memmove(rxBuffer, msg_header_p, sizeof(MsgHeader));`, but I guess I should await feedback on my "alias cast" first!

Comment: I guess this way isn't safe. With such a non-trivial type-conversion the compiler might lose that  msg_header_p and rxBuffer point to the same memory place and if you write to rxBuffer later and try to read from msg_header_p you might get serious side-effects.

Comment: @user3544995, the point of the `memmove` is to stop the compiler from having to think about that issue. You're right that there would be problems if I wrote to `rxBuffer` later. But if I did that, I could modify the code accordingly. The point of the `memmove` is to place a form of 'barrier' in the code. After the memmove, `msg_header_p` is accessible (and `rxBuffer` is not). Before the memmove, it's the other way around. And the memmove ensures that the "bit pattern" that *will be* accessible at the destination (`msg_header_p`) is the same pattern that *was* at the source (`rxBuffer`).

Comment: @AaronMcDaid: I find it absurd that C and C++ still don't have any sort of "aliasing barrier" intrinsic, and that poorly-written rules which were supposed to allow "optimization" instead make it necessary to write code which will on many compilers run slower, and which is certainly harder to read, than code which would be possible if there were an intrinsic that would indicate "these things might alias" but didn't have to do any actual work.

Comment: Hm, it looks like you want to exploit C's [effective type](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/object#Effective_type) rules via the `memmove()` - however, this would only work with a buffer object that doesn't have a declared type - and no effective type, yet. But in OP's example `rxBuffer` **does**  have a declared type.