# Avoiding strict aliasing violation in hash function

Tags: c++, strict-aliasing

How I can avoid strict aliasing rule violation, trying to modify `char*` result of sha256 function.

Compute hash value:

```
std::string sha = sha256("some text");
const char* sha_result = sha.c_str();
unsigned long* mod_args = reinterpret_cast<unsigned long*>(sha_result);
```

than getting 2 pieces of 64 bit:

```
unsigned long a = mod_args[1] ^ mod_args[3] ^ mod_args[5] ^ mod_args[7];
unsigned long b = mod_args[0] ^ mod_args[2] ^ mod_args[4] ^ mod_args[6];
```

than getting result by concat that two pieces:

```
unsigned long long result = (((unsigned long long)a) << 32) | b;
```

Comment: I really hopu the actual string you compute the hash for is longer than what you show, or you will be indexing out of bounds when calculating `a` and `b`.

Comment: @Joachim Pileborg: sha256 must always return 32 bytes of hash.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12612488/aliasing-t-with-char-is-allowed-is-it-also-allowed-the-other-way-around

Comment: That still doesn't mean you can go out of bounds of the input data, you need to pad it.

Comment: @Joachim Pileborg: How can I do it?

Comment: You have bigger problems than strict aliasing violation. How did you get that `char* sha_result = sha.c_str()` to compile?

Comment: @Lightness Races in Orbit: it compiles for me (MSVC).

Comment: @Lightness Races in Orbit: What do you mean?

Comment: @Mykola: It shouldn't. `sha.c_str()` is a `const char*`. Note the `const`.

Comment: @Lightness Races in Orbit: Thank you!)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As depressing as it might sound, the **only** true portable, standard-conforming and efficient way of doing so is through `memcpy()`. Using `reinterpret_cast` is a violation of strict aliasing rule, and using `union` (as often suggested) triggers undefined behaviour when you read from the member you didn't write to.

However, since most compilers will optimize away `memcpy()` calls, this is not as depressing as it sounds.

For example, following code with two `memcpy()`s:

```
char* foo() {
  char* sha = sha256("some text");
  unsigned int mod_args[8];
  memcpy(mod_args, sha, sizeof(mod_args));
  mod_args[5] = 0;
  memcpy(sha, mod_args, sizeof(mod_args));
  return sha;
}
```

Produce following optimized assembly:

```
foo():                                # @foo()
        pushq   %rax
        movl    $.L.str, %edi
        callq   sha256(char const*)
        movl    $0, 20(%rax)
        popq    %rdx
        retq
```

It is easy to see, no `memcpy()` is there - the value is modified 'in place'.

Comment: Does anything in the C++ Standard indicate that it doesn't inherit C99's awful rules about `memcpy`?