# Converting byte array to unsigned long in C++

Tags: c++, pointers, char

I am reading in binary data from a file:

```
char* buffIn = new char[8];
ifstream inFile(path, ifstream::binary);
inFile.read(buffIn, 8);
```

I then want to convert the char* read in (as binary) to an unsigned long but I am having problems - I am not quite sure what is going on, but for instance 0x00000000000ACD gets interpreted as 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFCD - I suspect all the 0x00 bytes are causing some sort of problem when converting from char* to unsigned long...

```
unsigned long number = *(buffIn);
```

How do I do this properly?

Comment: I wanted to suggest a solution but the question is already closed.:)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since `buffIn` is of type `char` pointer, when you do `*(buffIn)` you are just grabbing one character. You have to reinterpret the memory address as an `unsigned long` pointer and then dereference it.

```
unsigned long number = *((unsigned long*)buffIn);
```

Comment: This according to the standards will be undefined behavior. char pointer need not have to be aligned to integer boundary.

Comment: Yes, I suppose that is obvious when you think about it. Thanks, will accept when I can.

Comment: @Sundar, it is aligned when pointing to allocated memory. Guaranteed by the standard. If the allocated memory is greater than `unsigned long`of course.

Comment: @Nick start of the allocated memory (using malloc/calloc) is always aligned to the max possible pointer boundary (perhaps long long), but not the memory not allocated by malloc/calloc. https://www.securecoding.cert.org/confluence/display/seccode/EXP36-C.+Do+not+convert+pointers+into+more+strictly+aligned+pointer+types

Comment: @Sundar, from the standard:
`1 Effects: The allocation function (3.7.3.1) called by a new-expression (5.3.4) to allocate size bytes of storage suitably aligned to represent any object of that size.`

Comment: @Nick, doesn't that mean `new char, will allocate pointer suitably aligned to represent any object of char size`??

Comment: @Sundar, you're right, the quote I wrote is for `new` only, but this one applies for `new []`, `1 Effects: The allocation function (3.7.3.1) called by the array form of a new-expression (5.3.4) to allocate size bytes of storage suitably aligned to represent any array object of that size or smaller.222)`

Comment: @Nick, I found http://stackoverflow.com/questions/506518/is-there-any-guarantee-of-alignment-of-address-return-by-cs-new-operation, look at the comments from BenVoigt

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/48424/discussion-between-sundar-and-nick)

Answer (score 0):

In addition to recasting the `char[8]` (which will only read the the first `unsigned long` - which is 32-bits in length), you can also use some simple bit-wise operations

```
unsigned long value = (((unsigned long)buffin[0]) << 24) | (((unsigned long)buffin[1]) << 16) | (((unsigned long)buffin[2]) << 8) | (unsigned long)buffin[3];
```

Comment: The unsigned longs are 64 bit on this platform. It's not meant to be portable code :)

Comment: @adrianmcmenamin Then you can do the same thing, just change the coefficients for the bit shifts.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like

```
unsigned long* buffInL = new unsigned long[2];
char* buffIn=(char*)buffInL;
ifstream inFile(path, ifstream::binary);
inFile.read(buffIn, 8);
```

Unlike other types, char* is allowed to alias.