# Unsigned char alias for struct

Tags: c++, templates, type-punning

Suppose I have this function:

```
template<class T>
uint8_t* toBytes(T&& obj)
{
  uint8_t* array = new uint8_t[sizeof(T)];
  for (int x = 0; x < sizeof(T); x++)
  {
    array[x] = reinterpret_cast<uint8_t*>(&obj)[x];
  }
  return array;
}
```

I am fairly certain that this is defined behavior (as long as don't expect the memory to look like any thing specific ... I think).

But now suppose I have another function:

```
template<class T>
T* toType(uint8_t* array)
{
  return reinterpret_cast<T*>(array);
}
```

Is the following defined?

```
class A { /* Members of A */ };

A a;
uint8_t array = toBytes(a);
A* anotherA = toType<A>(array);
```

Comment: Returning address of non-static local variable is bad because the variable will vanish on returning from the function and the returned address is useless.

Comment: @MikeCAT Sorry ment to have a new in there....I will edit

Comment: For `toBytes` use placement new: `return new (array) T(obj);

Comment: @piotr What if I don't have a copy constructor?

Answer (score 1):

I think it's undefined due to alignment issues. `new uint8_t[sizeof(T)];` doesn't necessarily return memory that is suitably aligned for `T`.

Comment: Dynamic memory (as returned by new) is alligned to any type.- see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/506518/is-there-any-guarantee-of-alignment-of-address-return-by-cs-new-operation