# How to create std::vector of char/std::byte where first byte is aligned to 16 byes, but there is no padding?

Tags: c++, alignment, alignas

There is an existing [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45490761/creating-a-word-aligned-char-vector) that requires C++03 and has no answer, so I will open a new one.

Problem I have is that I want to have `std::vector` of `std::byte`, but so that `.data()`(first element of data array) is 16 byte aligned.

`alignas` on wrapped char does not help because I do not want to have alignment gaps in the array.
In other words I want to keey alignment of 1 for elements, but I want alignment of 16 for the array.

Ideally I would like to avoid using a custom allocator. 
If there is any TBB or boost vector that does what I want that would be also great.

Comment: How about wrapping the `std::vector` and a `alignas(16) std::byte` into a class?

Comment: On platforms where maximum native alignment is 16 or greater, you need to do nothing special if you use the default allocator.

Comment: @user463035818 OK, but I mean there may be a C++11 solution that nobody posted as an answer to that Q

Comment: Answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12942548/making-stdvector-allocate-aligned-memory

Comment: ah ok you meant "requires c++03" in the sense of "the other question requires c++03 but no later standard", sorry misunderstood

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Aligning the data in a vector ain't provided by default. Not even for aligned classes.

The best way of doing alignment is with the [aligned_allocator](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_65_0/boost/align/aligned_allocator.hpp) of boost.

Unfortunately, it doesn't prevent padding, it even overallocates to adapt the pointer on the alignment. From C++17, it can used [aligned new](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/new/operator_new) (see `std::aligned_val_t` overloads). However, all implementations I've seen actually use the same trick.

An alternative is allocating a whole page at once, and do your own memory management with a custom allocator. You can do it, though it might take a lot of time to do correctly.

Comment: nitpick: you should provide link to aligned new since it is quite tricky to google for it, I assume you mean overloads taking std::align_val_t ?

Comment: Yes, indeed, I'll add it